# ¿Porque mi proyecto en Flutter necesita el JDK?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Estoy en las primeras etapas de mi aprendizaje en Flutter y me gustaría comprender por qué es necesario tener el Kit de Desarrollo de Java (JDK) vinculado en mi equipo para que mi aplicación funcione. Entiendo cuál es la solución (descargar el JDK y configurar las variables de entorno), pero me gustaría saber por qué esto es necesario. Tenía entendido que Android Studio incluía en su instalación el Android SDK y el JBR, que, según lo que leí, es similar al JDK pero está enfocado en el desarrollo móvil.

Mi pregunta surgió cuando instalé el JDK 21 y me encontré con la sorpresa de que aparecían errores relacionados con la incompatibilidad con Gradle. Tuve que desinstalarlo y volver a instalar el JDK 17. Lo peor de todo fue que, cuando desinstalé el JDK 21, el desinstalador de Oracle no eliminó por completo la carpeta en la que estaba ubicado. A pesar de que ya había modificado las variables de entorno para apuntar al JDK 17, mi aplicación Flutter seguía haciendo referencia al JDK 21. Tuve que eliminar manualmente esa carpeta para solucionar el problema, lo que me dejó con inquietudes acerca de Android Studio.

[image: Error al ejecutar el proyecto]

Answer (score 0):

Aun cuando Flutter está construido con el lenguaje de programación Dart, depende de la máquina virtual Java (JVM) para ejecutar las herramientas de Flutter y algunas de las dependencias subyacentes de Android. Por lo tanto, el SDK de Flutter requiere la presencia de un Java Development Kit.

Answer (score 0):

Es requisito indispensable instalar el JDK y tenerlo configurado en las variables de entorno, la razón es que al usar `Android Studio` u otras IDEs para trabajar con `Flutter` requieren `JDK`.

Instala el JDK:
https://www.oracle.com/mx/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html

**Deberías usar como máximo la versión 17, ya que hasta el día de hoy (oct 2023) las últimas versiones de `Android Studio` soportan como máximo la versión 8.X del plugin `Gradle` y, por lo tanto, soportan como máximo `JDK` 17**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa:
https://developer.android.com/build/jdks

El error que muestras en la imagen indica que debes agregar en las variables de entorno, la variable JAVA_HOME, indicando la ruta a tu JDK.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]